# When i run android project on my android mobile samsung j7 prime, mobile can't give permission

Tags: java, android

Mobile can't give permission...

Allow USB debugging?

The computer's key fingerprint is:

```
CA:66:EB:D1:B0:EB:01:3B:CC6F:98:C6:2B:C5:61:E4
```

Always allow from this computer to cancel, ok or error
(because an aap is obscuring a permission request, setting can't verify your request)

Comment: Could you write more about tools you are using and some info about your application?

Comment: using android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1: App settings > grant all permissions.

#### Option 2: Remove file manager.

> Regarding your permission issue on your phone, the problem may be
> caused by an app called "File manager" Either you can uninstall it, or if you want to keep it, go
> in "Settings -> Applications -> Settings -> Draw over other apps" and
> set the value to "No" for "File manager". If you don't find still...Go
> to settings and search 'draw over other apps'. Restart the device.

Comment: In setting i can't find " draw over other apps". Any other solution?

Comment: Do you have developer mode enabled?

Comment: android version 7.0